# How to call a jQuery by onRowSelect ajax event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a jQuery function who is executed by 'change' event from a value picked in a `<select>` tag.
But now I don't need the `<select>` because I'll force that value inside of my jQuery function.

My page uses JSF and PrimeFaces).

My jQuery function:

```
var table = '#myTable'
$('#maxRows').on('change', function(){ //Event who need to be changed
    $('.pagination').html('')
    var trnum = 0
    var maxRows = parseInt($(this).val()) //This will be changed for -> var maxRows = 10
    var totalRows = $(table+' tbody tr').length
    $(table+' tr:gt(0)').each(function(){

...more code
```

(Obs.: This function apply 'pagination' in my `<table>` )

My **old** select:

```
<select id="maxRows">
    <option value="5">5</option>    
    <option value="10">10</option>  
    <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
```

The question is: I'll cannot use the same 'change' event because the `<select>` will not longer exists anymore, how can I use the jQuery function from now on? It is possible by onRowSelect (example bellow) ajax event?

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect listener="????" />
```

Comment: take the function out of the onchange call, give it a name, call it whenever you want

Comment: Ok, probably will be like this: `function functionName(params){...`, but and about the call do you know how can I do it from a onRowSelect event?

Comment: Work it, function: `function paginateTable(maxRows){ ...` and the call: `<p:ajax event="rowSelect" oncomplete="paginateTable(10)"/>. Thank you!`

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

**Function**

```
function paginateTable(maxRows){
...
```

**Function call**

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" oncomplete="paginateTable(10)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution can be

1. hide #maxRows el with css (display: none)
2. on ajax complete set  value ($(#maxRows).val(15))
3. trigger 'change' event ($(#maxRows).trigger('change'))

Alternatively you can move listener function to separate one and call it by name.

Comment: Eugene, the code of second step should be like this: `<p:ajax event="rowSelect" oncomplete=" ($(#maxRows).val(15))"`?

Comment: Euegene, I hided the `<select>` element like you told, only the function call I made different. Thank you anyway.